# IsSpreadsheetFile function in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I searched for `IsSpreadsheetFile` on the internet and cannot find many results. The reason I'm interested with this function is due to an article posted by Raymond Camden: [ColdFusion Sample Upload and Parse an Excel File](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/05/31/ColdFusion-Sample-Upload-and-Parse-an-Excel-File)

He uses `IsSpreadsheetFile` function to determine if a file is a spreadsheet or not. I tested it, it works when my file extension is `.xls` but it doesn't work when it is `.xlsx`.

I cannot find any more explanation on the `IsSpreadsheetFile` function in ColdFusion documentation other than from Raymond's blog. How can I validate a spreadsheet other than using the `IsSpreadsheetFile` function?

**Update:**

Here are portions of my code that leads to calling IsSpreadsheetFile function:

```
<CFIF MyFileExt NEQ "xls" AND MyFileExt NEQ "xlsx">
    <CFLOCATION url="../index.cfm?p=home&err=Please upload excel only.">
<CFELSE>
    <CFSET ExcelObj = cfcomponents.Val_EXCEL(session.groupname,load_year)>   
    <CFSET ValidationResult = ExcelObj.IsExcelFile('GL',InstDirPath,FileName)>

    ....... codes continue on here after calling IsExcelFile method...
</CFIF>
```

Here is the IsExcelFile method:

```
<CFFUNCTION name="IsExcelFile" hint="Validate file.">
    <cfargument name="AppName" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="InstFileDir" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="InstFileName" type="String" required="TRUE">

    <cfset PathToExcelFile = "#Trim(arguments.InstFileDir)#/#Trim(arguments.InstFileName)#">

    <cfdump var="#PathToExcelFile#"><br>

    <cfdump var="#isSpreadsheetFile(PathToExcelFile)#"><br>
    <cfoutput># isSpreadSheetObject(PathToExcelFile)# NOT an Object</cfoutput>
    <cfabort>

     ......
</CFFUNCTION>
```

Note: The files definitely have .xlsx and .xls extensions. I created an .xls file by re-saving the .xlsx file to Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls) from Excel Workbook (*.xlsx).

Comment: You couldn't find this?  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isspreadsheetfile.html.  Also, elaborate on `not working when it's .xlsx`

Comment: That function does work with .xlsx files. It is likely a problem with your code. As phrases like "doesn't work" are very ambiguous, please update your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a brief description of the expected versus actual result.

Comment: When I uploaded .xlsx file the IsSpreadsheetFile function return "NO" instead of "YES". When I uploaded a .xls file it returns "YES". That's what I meant by "Not working" in my previous post. I read Ray Camden's blog and it says this function can validate both xls and xlsx but that is not the case for me. I also cfdump to see if my xlsx file is seen as an object by using isSpreadSheetObject(PathToExcelFile). This returns "NO", it's NOT an object. Is there another way to validate if a file is a spreadsheet file ?

Comment: (Edit)  Start with something simpler. Create a test page and just run the function with a hard coded path of an XLSX file only, ie `#isSpreadsheetFile("C:\path\to\someFile.xlsx")#`. What does it return? It is worth nothing, that function returns false for bogus/non-existent file paths. So be sure to verify the path is valid with `FileExists()`.

Comment: It's not complicated, I just submit the form and it is a simple form with only three fields. I added FileExists function and upload an xls file then an xlsx file and this is the result:  this is the result when I uploaded an xls file: Path to file: /space/users/www/advfiles/ES/alumni2151_4_lessrow2_crr.xls
FileExist x: YES
isSpreadsheetFile(PathToExcelFile) : YES
isSpreadSheetObject(PathToExcelFile): NO NOT an Object

Comment: This is the result when I uploaded an xlsx file:  Path to file: /space/users/www/advfiles/ES/ES_TestFile.xlsx
FileExist x: YES
isSpreadsheetFile(PathToExcelFile) : NO
isSpreadSheetObject(PathToExcelFile): NO NOT an Object

Comment: It is not that I do not believe you, but ... when troubleshooting it is always best to reduce things to the *absolute minimum* to rule out anything else that might interfere or skew the results, such as an upload. Since I tried both Raymond's example and a simple IsSpreadsheetFile(HardCodedPath) with CF10.0.20 and it works fine (returns "YES"), so something must be different, ie CF Version, test file used, etcetera. A) What is your exact CF version `<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion#">` ? B) Do you get the same result with a simple testing using a hard coded path?

Comment: Also try it with a few different xlsx files (ideally from different sources) to rule out it being a problem with that specific file.